# Solutions of linear PDE in the sense of distributions

Tags: partial-differential-equations, distribution-theory

Let us consider the wave equation written in the form
$$
\partial_{tt}\phi-\Delta\phi+\phi=0.
$$
By a Fourier transform, this takes the form
$$
(k_0^2-{\bf k}^2-1)\phi(k)=0.
$$
This has as a solution, in the sense of distributions,
$$
\phi(k)=A(k)\delta(k_0^2-{\bf k}^2-1).
$$
It is easy to see that, by Fourier transforming back,
$$
\phi(x)=\int\frac{d^3k}{(2\pi)^3}\left(\frac{A({\bf k},\sqrt{{\bf k}^2+1})}{2\sqrt{{\bf k}^2+1}}e^{i{\bf k}\cdot{\bf x}-i\sqrt{{\bf k}^2+1}t}-\frac{A({\bf k},-\sqrt{{\bf k}^2+1})}{2\sqrt{{\bf k}^2+1}}e^{i{\bf k}\cdot{\bf x}+i\sqrt{{\bf k}^2+1}t}\right)
$$
that appears as a general solution of the equation we started from.

My questions are the following:

- Is this approach sound to solve a linear PDE?
- What does it happen to the Dirac equation $(i\gamma\cdot\partial-1)\psi=0$ using this technique?

Comment: As long as $\phi$ can be assumed to not grow too fast (so that it is a Fourier transformable distribution), it is sound to use the Fourier transform to solve a linear PDE.

Comment: Thanks a lot @md2perpe. Indeed, it appears that the textbook solution comes out naturally, provided I change the integration variable as ${\bf k}\rightarrow -{\bf k}$ in the second term.